# Parser for MIB files in Java

Tags: java, parser, snmp

I'm working on an SNMP Manager in Java.
I have multiple MIB files that I want to parse as objects, so I can use their data within my code.

In order to do that, I need a good MIB file parser that can convert the data to structures, and provide comfortable API (in Java of course) so I could use them.

Does anyone know one? (preferably open source)
Thanks.

Comment: Upvote, but curious as to why you are reinventing the wheel when there are free (for commercial use) MIB viewers out there?

Comment: @Mawg I want to use the data within my code, so I want to load it as an object that will be easily accessible from the code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's not really clear from your question. Maybe you ought to edit it?

Comment: @Mawg Thanks for the remark, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if [this](https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/) will help you. It seems to be an SNMP library for .NET (which I do not use).

---

Alternatively: 
I long ago gave up handcrafting parsers and moved to Lex/Yacc (later Flex/Bison).

Then I discovered [Antlr](https://www.antlr.org/) which allows you to write your own grammar and syntax rules and generate source code in many languages to parse those rules.

You appear to be lucky in that someone has already created a free SNMP grammar parser – see https://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html

Either of those should probably help you, but I want to wax lyrical here on Antlr, which is an incredible timesaver.

In addition to letting you define your grammar in a visual way, with  a nice GUI (workbench plus plug-ins for Intellij, NetBeans, Eclipse, Visual Studio Code, and jEdit.), it allows you to visualize your grammar, as a graphical parse tree, and to  visually debug (tutorial [here](http://antlrv3ide.sourceforge.net/doc/gettingstarted/basictutorial/debuggingantlrgrammars.html)), stepping through the element which you are parsing, watching it pass through your parser and easily spotting errors in your grammar.

[image]

See the [mega tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/) for more.

Comment: See also https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/tree/5c721d5de4cc84bbe07b711d999ee55ee3a90533/lib/ANTLR